# Getting a "405 - Method Not Allowed" error on a D2L post call that used to work

Tags: desire2learn

I have a mobile app that posts topics to our LMS (basically white board pictures) that was working for a few years now without a hitch. However, starting this fall semester, I am getting the error below. I asked our LMS people and they are unaware of why it is happening but did say we are on the continuous delivery model.

```
{
"type": "http://docs.valence.desire2learn.com/res/apiprop.html#method-not-allowed",
"title": "Method Not Allowed",
"status": 405,
"detail": "The POST method is not allowed on this resource.",
"allowed_methods": [
    "GET",
    "HEAD"
]
}
```

Here is the call and json that used to work:

```
/d2l/api/le/1.25/28866/content/modules/4923001/structure/

{"IsHidden": false, "IsLocked": false, "ShortTitle": "170905_080423", "Type": 1, 
      "DueDate": null, "Url": "170905_080423.jpg", 
      "StartDate": null, "TopicType": 1, "EndDate": null, "Title": "170905_080423"}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There appears to be a defect in the Brightspace LE v1.25 API contract on the [/d2l/api/le/1.25/(orgunitId)/content/modules/(moduleId)/structure/](http://docs.valence.desire2learn.com/res/content.html#post--d2l-api-le-(version)-(orgUnitId)-content-modules-(moduleId)-structure-) action route that suppresses the availability to use that route with `POST` (in order to add new child modules or topics to the content module structure).

The workaround is to use an API contract between 1.22 and 1.24 if you need to use `POST` with this route (support for the `base64` query parameter was added with 1.22, so picking that contract up to 1.24 may be pertinent; if you don't need that feature, you can use an earlier contract, but, if you were previously using a contract between 1.22 and 1.24 reverting to that contract for `POST` is likely the best workaround).